# excel text to time

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table with the time formatted with text like the example below. I need to convert the time from a text string into a usable format. I would be happy if I could get it all in the same format I.E. everything in seconds and work from there. I know I could do this using a helper column and a very long ugly IF left, right, mid formula and divide everything but I am working with thousands of these daily and would love to automate it better with a dynamic formula or VBscript that made these easier to work with.

```
     A         B
1 Server(A)  15d 3h 39m
2 Server(E)  3h 36m 44s
3 Server(C)  4m 3s
4 Server(B)  44s
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't elegant, but it would work as a UDF as long as your format is as described:

```
Public Function timeStringToSeconds(strIn As String) As Long
    Dim values
    values = Split(strIn, " ")
    For Each v In values
        Select Case Right$(v, 1)
            Case "d"
                timeStringToSeconds = timeStringToSeconds + CLng(Left$(v, Len(v) - 1)) * 86400
            Case "h"
                timeStringToSeconds = timeStringToSeconds + CLng(Left$(v, Len(v) - 1)) * 3600
            Case "m"
                timeStringToSeconds = timeStringToSeconds + CLng(Left$(v, Len(v) - 1)) * 60
            Case "s"
                timeStringToSeconds = timeStringToSeconds + CLng(Left$(v, Len(v) - 1))
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

You could use it simply by doing this: in C1 for example: `timeStringToSeconds(B1)`
Or run it on a range by doing something like this:
`range.value = timeStringToSeconds(range.value)`

Answer (score 0):

Another UGLY way to achieve your strings into a **usable format** like dd:hh:mm:ss. Ofcourse if you need only seconds, we could also improvice that ;)

Please comment once you have tried out. I would call this sort of a situation as a **multi-delimiter split combine** :) where we treat `d, h, m, s` as delimiters. There can also be solutions using `split` function and `regexp`

**dd:hh:mm:ss**

Code:

```
Function multiSplitCombine(ByVal strTime As String) As String
Dim delimsArray(0 To 3) As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    'set delimiters
    delimsArray(0) = "d"
    delimsArray(1) = "h"
    delimsArray(2) = "m"
    delimsArray(3) = "s"

    If Len(strTime) = 0 Then
        multiSplitCombine = "00:00:00:00"
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = LBound(delimsArray) To UBound(delimsArray)
        '-- get the position of the delimiter
        j = InStr(1, strTime, delimsArray(i))

        '-- if the delimiter is not found
        If j = 0 Then
            '-- insert 00: into the position after earlier previous delimiter replacement
            strTime = Left(strTime, k) & "00:" & Right(strTime, Len(strTime) - k)
        Else
            k = j
           '-- replace delimiter with semicolon
            strTime = Replace(strTime, delimsArray(i), ":")
        End If
    Next i

    '-- strip that last extra semi colon
    strTime = Trim(Left(strTime, Len(strTime) - 1))

    '-- remove internal white spaces
    strTime = Replace(strTime, " ", "")

    '-- back to sheet
    multiSplitCombine = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(strTime, "dd:hh:mm:ss")
End Function
```

**in seconds**

Here what you need to change in above code,

- Change function name to `splitToSeconds`
- replace everything after `strTime = Replace(strTime," ", "")` by adding following code

  ```
  '-- dd:hh:mm:ss format
  strTime = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(strTime, "dd:hh:mm:ss")    

  '-- split by semicolon
  s = Split(strTime, ":")

  '-- it has to be 4 elements since the format we insert is d:h:m:s
  splitToSeconds = CDbl(s(0)) * 24 * 60 * 60 + _ 
                   CDbl(s(1)) * 60 * 60 + CDbl(s(2)) * 60 + CDbl(s(3))
  ```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Solomon here is another solution, do try it out ;)